# Find $\alpha$ such that $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{|x|^\alpha y}{x^2 + y^2} = 0$. Can I simply move to polar coordinates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, probability-limit-theorems

This is the full exercise:

> Given function:
>
> $$f(x, y) = 
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{|x|^\alpha y}{x^2 + y^2},  & \text{if }(x,y) \ne (0, 0) \\
> 0, & \text{if } (x,y) = (0,0)  \\
> \end{cases}$$
>
> a. find all $\alpha$ such that $f$ continous at $(0, 0$).

I have seen this solutions in many example, and I tried it here:

> In order that $f(0, 0)$ will be continous, then $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{|x|^\alpha y}{x^2 + y^2} = 0.$
>
> Write $x = r\cos\theta, y = r\sin\theta$ where $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$ and $r \to 0$.
>
> $$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{|r|^\alpha|\cos^\alpha\theta| r\sin\theta}{r^2(\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta)} = \lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{r|r|^\alpha|\cos^\alpha\theta|\sin\theta}{r^2} \implies \alpha > 1.$$

The answers sheet confirms my answer,

But I wonder whether it's a valid way to find the limit or I just had luck?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: When denominator is $x^2+y^2$, polar coordinates are usually a very good idea, so it wasn't luck. Need to show nothing $1$ or under will work.

Comment: and one more thing when you have changed to polar co-ordinates the limit is $$\lim_{ r \to 0}$$

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you! Is it true for only $x^2 + y^2$ or for any $x^{2\alpha} + y^{2\alpha}$?

Comment: It should often work, letting $x^\alpha=r\cos\theta$, $y^\alpha=r\sin\theta$.